# ALTER table to increase column size does not reflect in History (versioned) table

Tags: sql-server

I am currently using SQL Server 2016 and I have a table with SYSTEM VERSIONING TURNED ON. My alter command to increase the column size does not reflect in the history table (versioned table). Please can you advise?

I created the table using the below command

```
CREATE TABLE Report (
    ReportId          INTEGER       NOT NULL,     
    ReportName        VARCHAR(300)  NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_RPT PRIMARY KEY (ReportId)
    )


ALTER TABLE Report
ADD ValidFrom DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL DEFAULT SYSUTCDATETIME(),
    ValidTo DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL DEFAULT CAST('9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999' AS DATETIME2),
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (ValidFrom, ValidTo);

ALTER TABLE ICEBERG.Report
SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = ICEBERG.ReportHistory));
```

I am now trying to modify the column size ReportName in this table but the change in column size does not reflect in the ReportHistory table.

```
ALTER TABLE ICEBERG.Report SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF); -- note comment below

ALTER TABLE ICEBERG.Report ALTER COLUMN ReportName VARCHAR(500) NULL;

ALTER TABLE ICEBERG.Report SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON); -- note comment below
```

**Please note** , I have tried to execute only the alter table command without turning SYSTEM_VERSIONING ON/OFF as above, even that does not help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ALTER table to increase column size does not reflect in History (versioned) table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522889/alter-table-to-increase-column-size-does-not-reflect-in-history-versioned-tabl)

Comment: Do not post the same question please.

Comment: Can we retain this and delete the other. There was some issue with the submit button and I might have created it twice by mistake

Comment: I havent created it so many times, there seems to be some issue with the submit button. Also not sure when I write a comment why its posting as a new post.

Comment: **You** need to delete the duplicates, and I would do it now.

Comment: @Sami I raised a custom mod flag about the tripled question

Comment: I have deleted the others

Comment: @megan sounds like youre having some strange issues